# Когда при создании объекта правильно использовать (()), а когда {}?

Tags: c++

Например, для std::vector,

```
std::vector<int> v1{1};
std::vector<int> v2((1));
```

конструкторы создадут разные векторы при внешней схожести вызова, v1 состоит из одного элемента со значением 1, а v2 из одного элемента со значением 0.

Вопрос, когда правильно использовать (()), а когда {} при создании любых объектов?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае проблема в том, что `{}` приводит к инициализации списком, т.е. элементами `initializer_list`. А в `()` сработает конструктор, который это значение отработает как *размер* создаваемого вектора...

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно, зачем двойные скобки `((...))`, когда одинарные `(...)` делают то же самое.

---

Никогда не используйте `foo{...}` со стандартными контейнерами. Используйте только `foo = {...}` или `foo(...)`. Пустые фигурные скобки использовать можно: `foo{}`.

Дело в том, что смысл `foo{...}` меняется в зависимости от типа элементов:

- `std::vector<int> v1{10};` = [10]
- `std::vector<std::string> v1{10};` = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

А вот дальше есть две противоположные позиции:

1. Стараться нигде не использовать `foo{...}` (пустые скобки все так же можно). По умолчанию использовать `foo(...)`, а для инициализации контейнера списком: `foo = {...}`.

   - Плюс: одинаковое правило для всех типов; не надо думать, где контейнер, а где нет.
   - Минус: нет защиты от сужающих преобразований, которую дают фигурные скобки.

   Исключение: создание временного объекта явно безопасного типа, вроде `std::tuple` или `std::array` (последний, хоть и контейнер, является агрегатом, т.е. не имеет никаких рукописных конструкторов, и поэтому безопасен).
2. Почти везде использовать `foo{...}`. А `foo = {...}` и `foo(...)` только для контейнеров и для шаблонного кода (в который может прилететь тип-контейнер).

   - Плюс: автоматическая проверка на сужающие преобразования.
   - Минус: надо следить, где контейнер (или где он может быть в шаблоне), а где нет; можно ошибиться.

Мне кажется (1) лучше. Если сужающие преобразования так беспокоят, то включать специальные варнинги против них и ловить их везде, а не только в конструкторах.

(1) считается более традиционным вариантом. (2) когда-то был новым модным вариантом, и если бы не прокол с контейнерами, был бы всем хорош.

В принципе, если отказаться от стандартных контейнеров и сделать свои, то их можно сделать так, чтобы обойти этот косяк: все конструкторы кроме одного с параметром `initializer_list` должны иметь какую-то дополнительную отметку, например принимать пустую структуру. Вот так:

```
struct with_size_t {};
inline constexpr with_size_t with_size;

my_vector<int> a{10}; // [10]
my_vector<int> a{with_size, 10}; // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Двойные скобки cppcheck рекомендует ставить, чтобы отличать объявление функции от определения переменной.

Comment: @Максим Это крайне сомнительно. Я никогда не видел, чтобы двойные скобки ставили где-то кроме мест, где промсходит most vexing parse.